# Set minDate to current date in DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using DateRangePicker for dates. I was trying to disable past dates by setting min date to current date as below.It does not do any thing.

```
$('.daterange-single').daterangepicker({ 
        singleDatePicker: true,
        minDate: today
    });
```

but it is working fine when you give actual date as below.

```
$('.daterange-single').daterangepicker({ 
        singleDatePicker: true,
        minDate: "7/11/2019"
    });
```

Please help me how to set minDate to current date in DateRangePicker

Comment: http://www.dotnetqueries.com/Article/105/bootstrap-datetimepicker-disable-past-dates

Comment: where is the variable 'today' defined?
you can use jquery-ui OR have a look at moment.js.... otherwise vanilla JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `minDate` at current date in daterangepicker. You can try the below code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1901,
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="birthday" />
```

Comment: When i run your code snippet above, why maxDate autofill in the input tag?

Answer (score 2):

set the value of `today` to the current date from moment `moment()`

`var today = moment()`

or simply to a date object

`var today = new Date()`

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  minDate: moment()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datetimepicker">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try setting a variable to contain today's date and use it as minDate

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //As January is 0.
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var todayDateString = dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy;

$('.daterange-single').daterangepicker({ 
    singleDatePicker: true,
    minDate: todayDateString
});
```